# Header not found when Firebase included as a podspec dependency in Cocoapods

Tags: xcode, firebase, cocoapods

I created a new podspec file which contains some dependencies.

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = "ChatSDK"
  s.version          = "4.2.5"
  s.summary          = "Chat SDK - Mobile messaging framework for iOS"
  s.homepage         = "http://chatsdk.co"
  s.license          = 'MIT'
  s.author           = { "Ben Smiley" => "ben@chatsdk.co" }
  s.source           = { :git => "https://github.com/chat-sdk/chat-sdk-ios.git", :tag => s.version.to_s }

  s.platform     = :ios, '7.0'
  s.requires_arc = true

  s.subspec 'Core' do |core|

    core.source_files = ['Core/**/*']

    core.dependency 'Firebase/Core'
    core.dependency 'Firebase/Database'
    core.dependency 'Firebase/Storage'
    core.dependency 'Firebase/Auth'
  end
end
```

I created a new Xcode project with Xcode 8.2 and added a podfile.

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

use_frameworks!

target 'PodTest' do

  pod "ChatSDK/Core", :path => "../"

end
```

I ran pod install using Cocoapods 1.2.0.

The project had an error message FirebaseAnalytics/FirebaseAnalytics.h file not found. This prevents the project from compiling. However, it works if I remove the use_frameworks! flag or if I add the Firebase dependencies directly to the Podfile.

**CocoaPods Environment**

```
   CocoaPods : 1.2.0
        Ruby : ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin16]
    RubyGems : 2.0.14.1
        Host : Mac OS X 10.12.2 (16C67)
       Xcode : 8.2 (8C38)
         Git : git version 2.10.1
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib
Repositories : master - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ dee0949e9974fff9df1e6dcacec3b0f1675165df
               master_old - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ 55393b63a3da4576423ef07b8d1f6f244594638d
               private - https://bensmiley@bitbucket.org/bensmiley/pods.git @ 4f14e0b26b6c6e249d49c8fa37d0eba40dde3d99
Installation Source

Executable Path: /usr/local/bin/pod
Plugins

cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.1
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
cocoapods-stats       : 1.0.0
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.1.2
cocoapods-try         : 1.1.0
```

A demo project for this issue is available [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/49xvnx3341k64hi/PodTest.zip?dl=0).

Comment: This appears to be a problem with the way the Firebase pods are setup. So far we've only been able to work around it by manually building the Firebase libraries using Carthage and adding them using the vendored_frameworks flag.